# How to add the treeview selected items in a listview columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, treeview, treeviewitem

[image]I want to add those selected items in a treeview to listview. Please Help me to get out of this...

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateListView(e.Node.Checked.ToString());
    }

    void PopulateListView(string path)
    {
        listView1.Clear();

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        if (di.Exists)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(d.Name));
            }

            foreach (FileInfo f in di.GetFiles())
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(f.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `e.Node.Checked.ToString()` is not a path. Try `PopulateListView(e.Node.ToString());` instead.

Comment: A TreeNode is a TreeNode and a ListViewItem is a ListViewItem ; you can either copy just the text or store references to the corresponding other type in the Tags of each item/node.

Comment: Your aim seems to be to get the full path in the listviewitem.text? th simplest way is to store the directory or fileinfo objects or at least the full path right in the treenodes when you fill the tree. then you can pull them out, casting to the type you used and get the path data to fill the lvi.text..